# ActiveMQ configuration to remove inactive destinations not working

Tags: activemq-classic

I followed the instructions in the [ActiveMQ documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/delete-inactive-destinations.html) with no success.  The relevant portion of the configuration file (`conf/activemq.xml`) looks like this:

```xml
<broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="localhost" dataDirectory="${activemq.data}"
        deleteAllMessagesOnStartup="true" schedulePeriodForDestinationPurge="60000">
  <destinationPolicy>
    <policyMap>
      <policyEntries>
        <policyEntry topic=">" gcInactiveDestinations="true" inactiveTimoutBeforeGC="300000">
[...]
```

Note the use of three attributes, as per the docs: `schedulePeriodForDestinationPurge` on the `broker` element, and `gcInactiveDestinations` and `inactiveTimoutBeforeGC` (sic) on the `policyEntry` element.

However, the broker (version 5.15.11) is not purging inactive destinations.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you're testing this to confirm that it isn't working as expected? Also, have you tried this on the [latest release](https://activemq.apache.org/components/classic/download/)?

Comment: I use the admin web interface (port 8161) to see listings of topics.  I expect the topics to go away after the inactivity interval, but they don't. Other topics do, however (the Advisory.* ones), so it isn't that the broker isn't cleaning up at all.  My test consists of three mutually interacting programs, whose interactions prevent a clean way to shut down the topics from within the programs (a sort of chicken-and-egg problem), so I'd like to use this purge feature of the broker as a fallback to keep the topic space clean.  (The application involves multiple copies of these triples.)

Comment: I tried 5.16.5 and couldn't even start - the web console is dead in the water with HTTP 503 Service Unavailable, and the activemq.log file has absolutely ginormous error messages (e.g. stack traces 100+ lines deep) stemming from a ClassNotFoundException in Jetty.  Which is strange, why should a pristine out-of-the-box install fail with artifacts missing?  Sigh.

Comment: That's odd. I just pulled own the *nix distro for 5.16.5, uncompressed it, and ran `./activemq console` from the `bin` directory and everything worked fine. I tried with both Java 11 and 8. There were no issues at all with startup or the web console.

Comment: Agreed, odd. I reinstalled, and this time the broker came up cleanly.  That bogon went away, but my problem remains.  The 'ActiveMQ.Advisory.*' topics created internally by the broker are cleaned up after 300000 milliseconds, as configured (and logged); but my app's topics are not. I also tried the suggested fix of adding `schedulerSupport="true"` to the `broker` element, without success.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure your '<broker ..' element has the scheduler support enabled

```
<broker ... schedulerSupport="true" ... >
```

Comment: No joy.  Not so sadly, because this smacked of voodoo, a mysterious undocumented "feature" (never a good sign). Could you explain please, why this was supposed to work?  Thanks!

Comment: gc of inactive destinations uses the scheduler support to time when to check for inactive destinations. Important to note-- inactive means no active messages or consumers. If there is still an active consumer for the topic (durable subscriptions, and wild card consumers count), the broker won't delete the destination.

Comment: In the web console, I see `Number of Consumers` is zero (as I would expect) for my "expired" topics, but they are not purged after the timeout interval (the corresponding `ActiveMQ.Advisory.*` topics are purged, however).  Could there be other active consumers despite the zero number showing?

Comment: And, what is an "active message" for a topic?  The concept is relatively obvious for a queue, but how does it apply to a topic? Would a cached message (using  `lastImageSubscriptionRecoveryPolicy`) count towards this?